# Have CXF/JAXB generate JAXBElement<Boolean> instead of boolean

Tags: jaxb, cxf, spring-ws, wsdl2java

I have a WSDL file in which one of the many operations simply returns a `boolean` instead of an object with fields:

```
<xs:element name="isUserActive" type="xs:boolean" />
```

To generate Java classes, I use CXF: `org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava`. The generated `Port` contains the following method signature:

```
@WebMethod(action = "isUserActive")
@WebResult(name = "isUserActiveResponse", targetNamespace = "http://company.com/1.0", partName = "parameters")
public boolean isUserActive(
    @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "isUserActiveRequest", targetNamespace = "http://company.com/1.0") com.company.IsUserActiveRequest parameters
) throws Exception;
```

I also get an `ObjectFactory` for the boolean:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://company.com/1.0", name = "isUserActiveResponse")
public JAXBElement<Boolean> createIsUserActiveResponse(Boolean value) {
    return new JAXBElement<Boolean>(_IsUserActiveResponse_QNAME, Boolean.class, null, value);
}
```

Unfortunately, Spring Boot doesn't understand that mapping and throws an exception when a client calls that endpoint:  `No adapter for endpoint [public boolean ...` so I manually change the generated `Port` to return a `JAXBElement<Boolean>` instead of a `boolean` and use the `ObjectFactory` to create such an object in the implementation:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE, localPart = "isUserActiveRequest")
@ResponsePayload()
public JAXBElement<Boolean> isUserActive(@RequestPayload IsUserActiveRequest request) {
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    boolean result = doSomething();
    return factory.createIsActiveResponse(result);
}
```

Obviously, whenever I re-generate the Java classes from the WSDL, those manual changes are discarded, so I'd like to know how I should configure `WSDL2Java` in order to generate the method signature as desired.

I've already tried to provide a binding-file setting `generateElementProperty="true"` but that would change the other generated classes as well by replacing their field's types to `JAXBElement<T>`. I'm just interested in that particular method overriding a primitive `boolean` as return type.